# Duplicate imports in Go Lang

Tags: go

In the scenario where I import this :

```
import (
      "fmt"
      "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
      "net/http"
      "log"
      )
```

But httprouter/router.go imports :

```
import (
        "net/http"
)
```

do I still need to import "net/http" in my go file?

Comment: If you want to use anything within the `net/http` package directly then yes

Comment: thanks @JackGore I guess my question seems stupid, there goes the last of my rep. But appreciate you taking the time answer.

Comment: For downvoters: this might not be trivial for someone starting with programming. "After all, the code is already loaded, right?". This question might be worth answering properly for newcomers (as long as it's not duiplicated. I've not checked it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your files only need to be concerned with which imports are used within *that specific file*.

You can try using [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) to see how it suggests things to be imported. [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?#package-names) has this to say:

> When a package is imported, the package name becomes an accessor for
>   the contents. After import "bytes" the importing package can talk
>   about bytes.Buffer.

which, pedantically, is not entirely correct as you can have multiple files in the same package and each needs to import whatever it requires (eg, 2 files in a package might each `import fmt`